# Can not create new table in Node.js and MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am a novice in NodeJs and MYSQL. I am following a tutorial on youtube and I am getting an error when I am creating a new table `"/createpoststable"`. It is just returning me the catch error I wrote `"error creating table"`. However, when I am going to my localhost, the page is showing up(`http://localhost:3000/createpoststable`) : `posttable created...`

What can be wrong?

```
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql");


const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database:'bonjour'
});


db.connect((err)=>{
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
        console.log("MySQL connected");  
});


const app = express();


app.get("/createdb", (req, res) => {
    let sql = 'CREATE DATABASE bonjour';
    db.query(sql, (err, result) =>{
        if(err){
            console.log("error creating database");
        }
        console.log(result);
        res.send("database created....");
    });
});


//create table
app.get("/createpoststable", (req, res) => {
    let sql = 'CREATE TABLE posts(id int AUTO_INCREMENT, title VARCHAR(255), body VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY id)';
    db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if(err){
            console.log("error creating table");
        };
        console.log(result);
        res.send("posttable created...");
    });
});



app.listen("3000", ()=>{
    console.log("Server started :D")
});
```

Comment: Use paretheses for the primary key: PRIMARY KEY **(** id **)**

Comment: Thanks, it is working. Do you recommend to use MySQL and NodeJS? I am doing a small job-listing website so I need a relational database this is why I am not using MongoDB

Comment: SO is not the right place to ask for technology recommendations. Not even in comments. However - I guess many projects are based on NodeJS + MySQL.